# Does the Request Per Second (rps) depends on framework/language?

Tags: express, go

I'm confused regarding what are the factors which affects the rps.

some say, django is slow as cannot handle a lot of concurrent request while the performance is more in node or golang.

in which scenario in the rps going to be maximum and why.

1. django app hosted on a vps without nginx
2. django app hosted on a vps with nginx
3. Express app hosted on a vps without nginx
4. Express app hosted on a vps with nginx

also i've created an express project and if i'm recreating the project in go-fiber, how much performance difference is going to be there and which aspect of my app are going to improve and why.

thanks in advance

Comment: More than anything else, the data tier and external API calls are likely to limit requests per second.  Node, express, and Go can all be run on an indefinite number of servers to handle requests per second.  Can the data tier handle bursts and throughput?  Go will be cheaper dollar per request because it has less overhead.  But you'll spend more money on the people than you will on the servers, so choose the framework and language that you can build a team around and then focus on the data tier performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting any project, don't think about performance. Think about the health and safety of the project and also about quick access to the market/production
From the four options you put forward, the answer will be:
Express app hosted with nginx/appache/caddy.
nginx/appache/caddy performs a lot of tasks, including the cache. This makes your application faster.
This does not mean that Django is slow. Django is still fast enough. The important thing is to choose the technology you are good at and enjoy development with.
Finally Go apps will be the fastest and safest too.
First, because it is a static type language, This gives speed and safety.
And because it is a compiled  language. This gives it speed and stability.
And because it uses all available cores (cpu) automatically, With other languages, exploiting all the available cores would be complicated.

Comment: so does nginx improves the concurrent request per second? also if make the same project with golang(fiber) will my concurrent request per second will improve. if yes then by what margin. This confuses me?

Comment: If your application is based on a database you will notice a slight improvement in responses per second.
The database is always the bottleneck in 90% of applications.
But you will notice a clear improvement in memory and processor consumption.
But if your application does not depend on the database, or you improve communication with the database, you will notice a huge improvement. Usually up to x10 faster than any application written in a dynamic language.